# Texto cortado na tela de análise de edições sugeridas

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, edição, interface-usuário

Recebi uma sugestão de alteração numa resposta mas a página têm um problema de CSS que não me permite ver o conteúdo. Faltam também algumas traduções aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sugestões para a tradução:

> Você pode aprovar, rejeitar ou melhorar a sugestão
>   **Aprovar:** no caso de a sugestão estar correcta
>   **Rejeitar:** se a sugestão  for incorrecta
>   **Melhorar:** no caso de a sugestão ser boa mas puder se melhorada
>   **Ignorar:** para ignorar e seguir para a proxima revisão

Comment: @Gabe, dá para corrigir isto?

Comment: Infelizmente uma arroba não vai notificar o Gabe aqui (ele nem comentou nem editou). Mas isso precisa de atenção urgente, está difícil analisar as edições assim.

Comment: Sinalizei esta pergunta com uma descrição em inglês, para ver se algum dev do site resolve. Este problema é irritante!

Comment: @bfavaretto, excelente. Concordo. Já tenho evitado algumas análises porque não tenho tempo de fazer um patch ou porque estou num browser sem DevTools

Comment: @bfavaretto, valeu! Resposta chegou :)

Comment: Eu [aproveitei uma deixa](http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/448/duplo-encoding-no-resultado-de-busca-por-duplicatas#comment918_476), e funcionou :)

Comment: @bfavaretto o erro está de volta :(

Comment: @Math Eu não vejo o erro, pelo menos não na fila de edições sugeridas. Onde você viu ocorrer? Tem um link?

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim, para mim todas as análises da fila de edição aparecem assim. Um exemplo: [link](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/110), [imagem](http://i.stack.imgur.com/K6J5R.png)

Comment: @Math Agora eu vi. Parece que o problema é só no meta, né?

Comment: @bfavaretto sim sim, e só na fila de edições sugeridas.

Comment: Deixei um comentário pro m0sa ali na resposta dele. @Math

Comment: @Math, achei melhor separar o caso do meta em outro bug report: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2039/texto-cortado-na-fila-de-edi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-sugeridas-do-meta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Todas as mensagens das filas de análise foram tornadas localizáveis, assim se ainda estiverem a ver partes em Inglês é porque os nossos tradutores ainda estão a trabalhar nisso.

O problema de CSS vai ser corrigido na próxima revisão a ser publicada (`2014.1.15.1855` no meta e `2014.1.15.1304` no site).

**Traduzido de:**

> All of the review queue texts were made localizable, so if you are seeing any english text there, that means our translators are still working on it.
>
> The CSS layout issue will be fixed in the next build that rolls out (`2014.1.15.1855` on meta and `2014.1.15.1304` on sites).

Comment: Thanks! The CSS issue was indeed the most important, we can live with the missing translations a little longer.

Comment: The problem apparently persists on meta, e.g. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/110. Should I "reopen" this issue, or post a new bug report?

Comment: I created a separate bug report for the meta issue, so this becomes less confusing.

Answer (score 7):

Acontece comigo também. Parece ser um problema da classe CSS `.question-summary`, que define uma largura insuficiente. Para corrigir, crie um item na barra de favoritos de seu navegador com a seguinte URL:

```
javascript:(function(){var newcss=".question-summary{width:100%}";if("\v"=="v"){document.createStyleSheet().cssText=newcss}else{var tag=document.createElement("style");tag.type="text/css";document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);tag[(typeof document.body.style.WebkitAppearance=="string")?"innerText":"innerHTML"]=newcss}})();
```

Então, ao abrir a página de análise de edit sugerido, clique no favorito e a largura deve se ajustar.

Essa solução é baseada na solução de Paul Irish para [injetar CSS usando bookmarklets](http://www.paulirish.com/2008/bookmarklet-inject-new-css-rules/). Testei no Chrome.

Comment: haha, bom patch :) +1

Comment: Estava olhando a fila de edições sugeridas e pulei vários itens por causa do bug. Queria ter visto sua resposta antes!

Answer (score 2):

O problema está em

```
.question-summary {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    padding: 12px 0 8px 0;
    width: 728px;        /* <-------- estilo problemático */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cfd9ce;
}
```

Vale lembrar que os sites da Stack Exchange utilizam jQuery, então fica simples de "arrumar" executando:

```
$(".question-summary").css("width", "100%");
```