# Texto cortado na fila de edições sugeridas do meta

Tags: bug, status-pronto, filas-de-análise, meta, interface-usuário

É o mesmo bug que já foi reportado e corrigido no site, em [Texto cortado na tela de análise de edições sugeridas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/78/texto-cortado-na-tela-de-an%c3%a1lise-de-edi%c3%a7%c3%b5es-sugeridas). No meta, ele ainda ocorre. Para uma descrição detalhada, ver a outra pergunta.